# Using SQL, how do you find the child number in a table from two columns where they are parent-child relationships?

Tags: mysql, sql, parent-child

[image]

From this table, after querying I want to get the child column that shows the number of the child for each id.

I want:

[image]

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information directly to your question preferably as editable text

Comment: So what is the result you want to achieve, based on that data?

Comment: As a new user stack overflow did not allow me to attach images directly. That's why I attached these links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A scalar subquery will produce the data you want. For example:

```
select
  t.*,
  (select count(*) from t b where b.parent_id = t.id) as child
from t
```